# Are blind men obligated in kiddush levana

Tags: halacha, rosh-chodesh-new-month, kiddush-levanah, handicap-disabled-impair, orach-chaim

According to Halacha are blind men obligated in kiddush levana on Rosh Chodesh or not? Or because of the fact they can not see the moon visibly, are they exempt? Is this question found amongst the Poskim?

Comment: Why ask about this blessing and not the blessing on rainbows (or a dozen other things)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Beur Halachah 426:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.426.1.2?lang=he) cites a dispute among the poskim about this, with Maharshal (R. Shlomo Luria) saying that yes, he should say it (because even though he can't see the moon, others can, and that's enough), and Maharikash (R. Yaakov Castro) saying no.

In practice, then, the Mishnah Berurah rules that it's best for him to have someone else say the brachah itself on his behalf, and the rest of the accompanying prayers he can say himself.